# RecyclerAdapter override methods(OnBindViewHolder and onCreateViewHolder) not called in RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to debug my code and My recycler view isn't giving any display. I am trying to use 2 recycler views with 2 different adapters whereby the below adapter code isn't working. I have tried applying logs on it and found out that onBindViewHolder and onCreateViewHolder are not being called. This has been on me for a while now. Below is my Adapter code.

```
onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new RecordsAdapter.MyNewAdapterHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.records_layout,parent,false));
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecordsAdapter.MyNewAdapterHolder holder, int position) {
        String str = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).getString("Name", "get");
        Toast.makeText(context, "str", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://milkdiary-farmer.firebaseio.com/");
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users").child("Users").child("Your Records");
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot childSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String value = childSnap.getValue().toString();
                    Toast.makeText(context, "value", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    holder.farmername.setText(value);
                    holder.farmerRecord.setText(value);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        //holder.setDetails(this.recordsArrayList1.get(position));
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return recordsArrayList1.size();
    }
```

Below is my Main Activity Code

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar3);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Records");
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(-1);
    getIntent().getStringExtra("username");
    RecyclerView recyclerView1 = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recycler);

    RecyclerView recyclerView2 = findViewById(R.id.records_recyclerview);
    recordsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    RecordsAdapter recordsAdapter = new RecordsAdapter(this,recordsArrayList);
    recyclerView2.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this,1));
    recyclerView2.setAdapter(recordsAdapter);
    recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recordsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    this.recyclerView = recyclerView1;
    recyclerView1.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    this.arrayList = new ArrayList();
    this.adapter = new MyAdapter(this, this.arrayList);
    this.recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, 1));
    this.recyclerView.setAdapter(this.adapter);

    fetch();
}
```

Comment: try call notifyDataSetChanged on adapter after this.recyclerView.setAdapter(this.adapter);

Comment: I have tried it and still not working

Comment: If you can provide demo project we can help with debugging.

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: can you show your database structure? (screenshot)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the updated code after you added the call to `notifyDataSetChanged` that multiple people have pointed at. Also note that the minimum implementation of `onCancelled` is: `public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { throw databaseError.toException(); }`

Comment: If you have items and the adapters and the layout manager, then the RecyclerView might just be too small to show.

Answer (score 1):

did you call `notifyDatasetChanged` on your Adapters when you fetched data and filled your arrayList?

Comment: I have tried it and still not working

Comment: show your fetch method, when and how you fill the array list?

Comment: The fetch method contains a different adapter which is working very well for me. The adapter by the name "RecordsAdapter" is what is not working well for me as no data is being displayed

Comment: you don't have access to this adapter when you filled "recordsArrayList" in other methods, declare "RecordsAdapter" in Activity  like  "adapter" and when you filled the "recordsArrayList" just call "recordsAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged()"